# Reading NiFi system properties not working with groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I've a variable defined in `nifi.properties` file in my system which I'm trying to read inside a `ExecuteScript` processor using `Groovy`. Below is I've tried:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

try
{
def newFile = new File(${config.password.file}).getText()

flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "passwordFile", newFile.toString())
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "errorStack",e.toString())
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

The value of `config.password.file` is absolute path to a file which contains the password which I need to use.

Not sure but this approach doesn't work. This is the error stack I'm getting:

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script90`

I tried to use the groovy functionality of reading the password from a file on my local machine via the code below and it works fine.

```
def filex = "C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\passwordFile.pass"
String passFile = new File(filex).getText()
```

Any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Also, based on the error stack I mentioned above, it doesn't mentions exactly what property is missing. Does anyone have any idea on how to customize the code as such it generates the error exactly which property is missing or something like it?

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is that NiFi Expression Language is not supported in the script body or within a script file provided by an ExecuteScript property, but what you want can still definitely be done.

How is `config.password.file` defined? Is it a user-defined property on the ExecuteScript processor? If so, the problem is getting access to a variable that has Groovy-specific characters such as period. Instead of being able to refer to them by name, you'll have to use the script's Binding, as follows:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

try {
  def newFile = new File(binding.getVariable('config.password.file').value).text
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "passwordFile", newFile.toString())
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)  
}
catch(e) {
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "errorStack",e.toString())
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

If it is not a property but a flow file attribute, try the following:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

try {
  def newFile = new File(flowFile.getAttribute('config.password.file')).text
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "passwordFile", newFile.toString())
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)  
}
catch(e) {
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "errorStack",e.toString())
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

The two scripts differ only in the newFile line, the former gets the property as a PropertyValue object from the Binding associated with the Script, the latter gets the value of the flow file attribute.

Comment: Thanks Mattyb. The value of `config.password.file` is absolute path to the filename, so.. `/tmp/workDir/passFile.pass` and it's defined in the `nifi.properties` file.

I realized the wrong I was doing in the approach. I was reading the variable which was not getting extrapolated into string. And thus the `new File($variable).getText` wasn't getting a string value. 

To resolve this, I added an updateAttribute processor to catch the variable and used that attribute as a flowfile property to pass in the `File` method.

Comment: You can do it without UpdateAttribute by using a user-defined property on ExecuteScript whose key is “config.password.file” and whose value is “${config.password.file}”, then before .value in my first example, add a call to evaluateAttributeExpressions()